# Does a Oracle procedure inherit the privileges of its creator?

Tags: oracle, privileges, procedure

I have 3 Oracle users A, B, C and want to use B (as intermediate) to import a table from C to A. When connected to B, I can run "create table A.T1 as select * from T1@C". But when I put the sql statement into a procedure that B creates/owns, I keep getting "ORA-01031: insufficient privileges". As sysdba, I have granted all rights (dba) to B. So what am I missing here? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you granted the following to user `B`?

```
sql> grant create any table to b;
```

Answer (score 5):

In an definer's rights stored procedure (the default), the only privileges that are available are those that are granted directly to the user, not those that have been granted through a role (like DBA).  So Pablo is correct that B would need to have the CREATE ANY TABLE privilege as a direct grant.

Comment: the default is "Owner Rights" not invokers.

Comment: @redcayuga - +1 and thanks for the catch!  You're absolutely right.  I updated my answer to reflect your correction.

Comment: "AUTHID DEFINER"... ;)  This is the default.  Alternative is "AUTHID CURRENT_USER" which I alway want to try...!